# ng-select: get selected object, preselect by Id

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of users (array of objects)

1. I need the selected user in `$scope.owner` for use elsewhere.
2. I need to pre-select a user by `Id` and have `$scope.owner` update with correct object values (e.g. user.Email, user.Address).
3. `$scope.item.UserId` needs to change based on the selected user.

This is what I have so far:

```
<select
    ng-model="owner"
    ng-change="item.UserId=owner.Id"
    ng-options="user as user.Company + ' - ' + user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName for user in users track by user.Id">
</select>
```

Currently **1.** and **3.** work, but when I pre select using:

```
$scope.owner = { Id: 1 };
```

Then I obviously don't all the values from `users` such as `user.Email`.

Anyone got ideas or advice?

Thanks, Lex

Comment: assuming you have the ID up front then should iterate array to set `owner` from the full data set in users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use $scope.owner = {Id:1} even it has same Id it is different instance then one created when iterating in ng-options.

When you get your list of users why not just set

```
$scope.owner = $scope.users[0]  
// or if you need to get by id just use 
$scope.owner = $scope.users.filter(...)[0]
```

Here is sample plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/5VZbdmBmtaDpkeLYQwft?p=preview